# GMail and bandwidth consumption lowering

Tags: networking, gmail, bandwidth

When I am roaming I tether my 'LG Optimus One' to my 'HP Mini' and check some of the forums in GMail in a browser often. It seems to be consuming a lot of network bandwidth. How do I minimize the network bandwidth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using https://mail.google.com/mail/?ui=html instead; this is the plain HTML page designed for slower connections, so presumably it uses less data.

Comment: Ben - it works - thnx - This link is not available in the default GMail page.

Comment: Yep, I remembered it existed because it usually shows it while the normal page is loading, so I quick snatched it from there.

Answer (score 0):

Only way i can suggest is

1. Move your gmail to classic theme
2. Sign out of messenger
3. Keep inbox mail size to minimum
4. Disable any google lab plugins you have installed.

I hope this helps. May not be accurate but it will help.

Comment: I don't see out 3 & 4 will help.

Comment: For 3: I guess because Gmail prefetches the mails to display them quicker. I don't think it'll prefetch images though. @Sathya

Comment: What i mean to say is: you have option how many emails to be displayed on one page. example: 25,50 100, 200 this will change loading time drastically

Comment: How to move to the classic theme?

Comment: open gmail->at far top right-> click on settings icon->Mail settings->Themes->classic

Comment: Also from about mentioned settings area disable buzz